# Does this sequence always end in zero? Sieving our primes.

Tags: number-theory

Given an integer $n$ consider the following sequence ( $p_k$ is the $k$'th prime)

$a_1=n-\lceil \frac{n}{p_1}\rceil$

$a_k=a_{k-1}-\lceil \frac{a_{k-1}}{p_k}\rceil$.

Can we prove for any $n\geq 7$ we have $a_{\pi(n)}=0$ ?

This question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382628/at-least-one-of-100-consecutive-integers-is-relatively-prime-to-all-natural-numb/1383805#1383805), this result would prove it is false for every integer over $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it for all $n\ge 7,\;$ because the are some counter-examples, the smallest such $n$ is $10$. We have $\pi(10)=4$ but
$$a_1 = 10 - \lceil 10/2 \rceil = 5 $$
$$a_2 = 5  - \lceil 5/3 \rceil = 3 $$
$$a_3 = 3  - \lceil 3/5 \rceil = 2 $$
$$a_4 = 2  - \lceil 2/7 \rceil = 1 $$
$$a_5 = 1  - \lceil 1/11 \rceil = 0 $$
So $a_{\pi(10)}=1$. Other counter-excamples are $n=12,16,28.$

I did not find larger counter-examples up to $n=10000.$

Comment: Thanks, so then we could conjecture it is true for $n\geq 29$ right?